# Adding each line from an input file into an array

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

I need to add the contents of every line (single word) of an user input text file into a separate element in an array. 
*I know an ArrayList is a better data structure for this problem but I am limited to using only an array.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a file name: ");
    System.out.flush();
    String filename = scanner.nextLine();
    File file = new File(filename);
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
    try (BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
        String line;
        int i=0;
        String[] words = new String[10];
        while((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
            words[i]=buffReader.readLine();
            System.out.println(words[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

The input file is simply:

```
Pans 
Pots 
opt 
sit 
it's
snap
```

Program output is below. It seems to be skipping every other line.

```
Pots
sit
snap
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading two lines per `while` loop iteration, one in the `while` condition, and the other in the first line of the loop body.  The result is that each iteration consumes two lines, and only the second of the two is printed.

Eliminate the second call in the loop body, so that you have one iteration of the loop (and one print statement) per line.

Answer (score 1):

Change the while loop as shown below. If while loop condition check, you are reading the line then again reading the line in first line in your while loop. So you are reading two lines and printing only one line.

```
 while((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line );
        i++;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null)
```

That line read and consumed the first input line and that is why you are not seeing ***Pans*** and the even indexed inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an ArrayList than just convert it to an Array using the toArray method? What are your limitations and why?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a file name: ");
    System.out.flush();
    String filename = scanner.nextLine();
    File file = new File(filename);
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
    try (BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
        String line;
        int i=0;
        String[] words = new String[10];
        //modify line = buffReader.readLine()
        while((words[i]=buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
                //modify //words[i]=buffReader.readLine();
            //words[i]=buffReader.readLine();
            System.out.println(words[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```